# Paint Panel Incorrect Rendering

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jpanel, paintcomponent

Here is what is going on:

I wanted to make a very basic paint program to practice using the paint method, working with graphics, using toolbars, et cetera.  I've been doing a lot of reading on how to do these things, and I'm sure I'm missing an important line of code somewhere because the paintpanel itself is rendering a JMenu that isn't supposed to be there.  I have a JMenu set up with actionListeners, but the one that is rendered as extra doesn't do anything and cannot be interacted with.  Here's a picture:  [image]

As you can see in the following image, I can paint over the menu and it still does not react at all.  Plus, this time you can see a radom button from a previous window in the program is added for some reason.  [image]

Here's where that button came from:  [image]

I am at a loss as to how to fix this, so here is the code for the relevant classes:

This is the panel that does the painting.
    package painter;

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.event.MouseInputListener;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class PaintPanel extends JPanel implements MouseInputListener
{
    //These two values will be used to determine where the mouse is and thus where to paint...stuff...
    public int xCoordinate, yCoordinate = -10;

    static Color currentColor = Color.black;

    public PaintPanel()
    {
        //These two methods simply attaches the mouse listener methods listed below to the actual panel.
        addMouseListener(this);
        addMouseMotionListener(this);
    }
    //This method is an overwritten version of the default paint method.  It's job is to render custom graphics
    //objects on the screen.  The Graphics g argument is the item responsible for doing the actual rendering.
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        // super.paintComponent(g);
         g.setColor(currentColor);
         g.fillRect(xCoordinate, yCoordinate, 10, 10);
    }

    @Override
    //This method, added because of the MouseInputListener implementation, is used when a user clicks the left mouse button.
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) 
    {
        xCoordinate = e.getX();
        yCoordinate = e.getY();
        repaint();
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    //This method, added because of the MouseInputListener implementation, is used when a user presses and holds the
    //left mouse button while moving the mouse.
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) 
    {   
        xCoordinate = e.getX();
        yCoordinate = e.getY();
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent arg0) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    public static void changeColor(Color color)
    {
        currentColor = color;
    }
}
```

This is the main class that adds in the PaintPanel, the menu, and later other buttons and such.

```
package painter;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import painter.menu.FileMenu;
import painter.menu.ToolsMenu;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
//This class will do the job of bringing together all the various sub-classes and rendering everything.
public class MainPainterGUI extends JFrame
{
    private JPanel menuPanel;

    private JMenuBar menuBar;

    //These values are going to be used to set an initial window size.
    private final short WINDOW_HEIGHT = 1000;
    private final short WINDOW_WIDTH = 1000;

    //This constructor will do the actual creation of the window.
    public MainPainterGUI()
    {
        //This does the same thing that setTitle does.
        super("Painter");
        //setTitle("Painter");

        //This method will set what the window is supposed to do when the red x is clicked.
        //Technically, the value passed is an integer.
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Obviously this method sets the initial size of the window.  It can be changed by the user however.
        setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH,WINDOW_HEIGHT);

        //This method sets the center of the window relative to whatever is passed.  In this case, null makes
        //the window appear in the center of the desktop regardless of the size.
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        menuPanel = new JPanel();

        menuBar = new JMenuBar();

        menuBar.add(new FileMenu());
        menuBar.add(new ToolsMenu());

        menuPanel.add(menuBar);

        //The add method simply attaches a component to whatever is calling, like a frame or another panel.
        //The BorderLayout is needed to use the draggable toolbar.
        add(new PaintPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(menuPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        //This will allow the window to be seen.  Make sure this method is last, as if 
        //a component is created afterwards it may not be visible.
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Those two classes should be the only ones relevant to the current problem, however let me know if other classes are needed.  I just didn't want to clutter the post with useless information.

Now, here is what I have tried already:

As you can see in the PaintPanel class, I had added a super.paintComponent(g); method call.  However, while this completely fixes my problem, it only paints a single black square at a time.  I would imagine because it's overwriting the panel with a paint call, then painting the square each time repaint is called.

Here's a photo with super.paintComponent(g) added:
[image]

I'm not sure if it matters, but I am using Windows 10.

Thanks for any help that can be provided.

Comment: You're not calling the super.paintComponent method but rather are commenting it out -- that is dangerous code and should not be done. If you want images to persist, put Points into an ArrayList and draw the ArrayList of points in your paintComponent. Either that or draw to a BufferedImage and then draw that in the paintComponent method. And always call the super's paintComponent method.

Comment: [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) has working examples that shows you how to persist painting by either using a `List` or a `BufferedImage` as suggested above.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I had commented out super.paintComponent(g) just while I was testing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to call `.repaint()` to make your UI less glitchy.

Comment: I actually have in my code.  If I never call repaint () it wouldn't paint anything.

Comment: At least it's not in the code you gave, except in one click handler. You should call it after changing the UI.